# Cross checking timezone requests in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime

I have a requirement where a video is uploaded, and has a "showDate" field specific to various states(timezones). This is defined in data as something like

```
{ "showDate_state1" : "2013-08-05 10:30 PM" }
```

When a request comes in, I will know the requesting state, so what I need to do is to figure out if the requesting date of the persons state is available to `showDate_state1`.

I'm thinking that using something like `convertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId`, where I get the utc time based on the timezones, compare and validate if it's available. Is that the simplest way?

Answer (score 0):

yes storing in UTC and displaying based in the time zone information is what you need, this may or may not be the simplest way but would solve your problem for sure.